# Span class will not allow me to add a hover when after an image, inside a link in an li

Tags: css, hover, html

I am trying to get my span text to have a hover effect, but it does not seem to be allowing me to.  Here is the HTML:

```
<span class="FooterTitles">Dealer Social</span>
<ul id="listitems">
<li class="footerList"><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"      alt="Follow Us On Twitter"><img  class="SocialImage" src="sm-twitter.png">
```

Twitter

Here is the CSS:

```
.FooterTitles {color:#fff;font-size:24px;}
#listitems{font-size:11px; color:#999;font-weight:bold;list-style-type: none!important;padding: 10px 0 0;margin: 0px;}
#listitems li {list-style-type: none!important;}
.footerList a:link, .footerList a:visited { text-decoration:none;font-size:11px;        color:#999;font-weight:bold;list-style-type: none!important;}
.footerList a:hover, .footerList a:active{font-size:11px; color:#fff!important;font-weight:bold;list-style-type: none!important;}
.footerList {margin-bottom: 10px;}
.SocialImage{padding-right:30px;}
.SocialText, .SocialText a:link, .SocialText a:visited {padding:0;font-size:11px; color:#999;font-weight:bold; position:relative; top:-10px;cursor:pointer;}
.SocialText a:hover, .SocialText a:active {padding:0; font-size:11px; color:#fff!important;position:relative!important; top:-10px!important;font-weight:bold!important;list-style-type: none!important;cursor:pointer;}
```

Has anyone had a similar problem that they notice why this wouldn't work?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Spans are absolutely capable of using the `:hover` psuedo-class just like any other element.  I wrote a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiAtlas/kEtSJ/) to demo this (though I'm sure you already know how it works).

In regards to your project, it appears you never specify `.FooterTitles:hover` only `.FooterTitles`.  Add that anywhere in your CSS and you should be good.